# Laravel 5.2 storing database in DB table

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5

Im new in Laravel so can anyone help me
I want to store the data in my database, i dont know if what i'm doing is right. Sorry for being a noob.

Here is my PaypalController

```
         <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

use Illuminate\Mail\Mailer;

use App\Maintenance;

use App\Time_tracker;


class PaypalController extends Controller {

 /**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}

/**
 * Show the application dashboard.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */

 public function index() {

 return view('paypal'); 

 }

 public function success() {
     $price = \Session::get('value_price');
 $value = $price;
 if($value == '465'){

         $paid = 'paid';
     DB::table('users')->insert([
     ['user_id' => $id],
     ['paid' => $paid]
     ]);
     $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
     $user = maintenance::find($id);
     $current_hour = $nerd->hour;
     $purchase_time = $purchase_time + 15;
     $current_hour = $current_hour + $purchase_time;

     $user = new Time_tracker;
         $user->hoursT = $current_hour;
     $user->paid = $paid;
         $user->date = $status;
         $user->save();




 }elseif($value == '700'){

    //   $paid = paid;
     DB::table('users')->insert([
     ['user_id' => $id],
     ['paid' => $paid]
     ]);
     $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
     $user = maintenance::find($id);
     $current_hour = $nerd->hour;
     $purchase_time = $purchase_time + 25;
     $current_hour = $current_hour + $purchase_time;

     $user = new Time_tracker;
         $user->hoursT = $current_hour;
     $user->paid = $paid;
         $user->date = $status;
         $user->save();


  }elseif($value == '1300'){

         $paid = paid;
     DB::table('users')->insert([
     ['user_id' => $id],
     ['paid' => $paid]
     ]);
     $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
     $user = maintenance::find($id);
     $current_hour = $nerd->hour;
     $purchase_time = $purchase_time + 50;
     $current_hour = $current_hour + $purchase_time;

     $user = new Time_tracker;
         $user->hoursT = $current_hour;
     $user->paid = $paid;
         $user->date = $status;
         $user->save();



   }


   return view('success');  

   }


   public function failed() {

     return view('failed'); 

 }


}
```

Here is my MaintenanceformController

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

use Illuminate\Mail\Mailer;

use App\Maintenance;

use App\Apply;

class MaintenanceformController extends Controller { 

  public function index() {
     $TownResults = DB::table('apply')->where('user', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get(); 
     return view('maintenanceform')->with('town_list', $TownResults);
  }

  public function multiple_upload() {

     $files = Input::file('images');
     $tasknumber = Input::get('tasknumber');
     $ordernumber = Input::get('ordernumber');
     $status = Input::get('status');
     $directions = Input::get('directions');
     $comments = Input::get('comments');
         $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
         $designation = Input::get('designation');

    $file_count = count($files);

    // start count how many uploaded

    $uploadcount = 0;


    foreach($files as $file) {

      $rules = array('file' => 'required'); //'required|mimes:png,gif,jpeg,txt,pdf,doc'

      $validator = Validator::make(array('file'=> $file), $rules);

      if($validator->passes()){

        $destinationPath = 'uploads/'.$tasknumber.'';

        $filename = ''.$tasknumber.'_'.$file->getClientOriginalName().'';

        $upload_success = $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);

        $uploadcount ++;



      }

    }

    $user = new Maintenance;

    $user->tasknumber = $tasknumber;
    $user->ordernumber = $ordernumber;
    $user->status = $status;
    $user->directions = $directions;
    $user->comments = $comments;
    $user->user_id = $user_id;
    $user->designation = $designation;

    $user->save();



   if($uploadcount == $file_count){

      Session::flash('success', 'Upload successfully'); 

      return Redirect::to('maintenance');

    } 

    else {

      return Redirect::to('maintenance')->withInput()->withErrors($validator);

    }


  }
}
```

I want to save the user_id, hoursT, paid, and purchase_time in DB table. Can anyone please help me. :)

Comment: There are so many errors, that's why i'm asking if my coding and logic is right and how will I make it work, so the problem here is how am i gonna save the data in Time_tracker table.

Comment: @S.I. Of course. There must be a lot of syntax error like $paid = paid; Very difficult to say that without seeing the whole class file. I don't know maintenance and $nerd? Those are came from where? And also $id in DB::table statement?

Comment: Let's start with the visible errors in your code. Your function is missing the closing brace. ```$paid = paid``` has a syntax error, I think it should be ```$paid = 'paid';``` (just guessing). ```$nerd``` is not defined anywhere in the code you posted. Your insert call (again just guessing) should be something like ```DB::table('users')->insert(['user_id' => $id, 'paid' => $paid]);```

Comment: And ```maintenance``` like @Kelvin pointed out. I missed that.

Comment: the maintenance is another DB table, the $nerd is just a mistake, I already editted that, the $id is the id of the user logged in.

Comment: Show us your full controller so we can help you quickly